# CoreData - NSPredicate formated with time range (NSTimeInterval)

Tags: sqlite, nsdate

I'm trying to find out how to go through my CoreData information and find objects that have a createdAt (part of my object as an NSDate) that is within a NSTimeInterval.  How do I set this up?

I've looked on the documentation at:
http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html

But I'm not finding anything there.

Do I need to create two time stamps and use SQL's BETWEEN?

Any help would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it doesn't make sense to check if an NSDate is within an NSTimeInterval, because NSTimeInterval just specifies a length of time, not its location. Instead, you want to use two separate NSDates specifying the beginning and end of your intervals.

Here's what it would look like (beginningTime and endTime are NSDates).

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"YourEntityName" inManagedObjectContext:yourContext];
NSPredicate *beginningPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"createdAt >= %@", beginningTime];
NSPredicate *endPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"createdAt <= %@", endTime];
request.predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:beginningPredicate, endPredicate, nil]];
NSArray *results = [yourContext executeFetchRequest:request error:NULL];
```